# React native low version project 0.59 not working in latest OS Sonoma

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm, cocoapods

My pod file is

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

 target 'WhizzTanzania' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for WhizzTanzania

pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.6'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.1'
pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
pod 'react-native-geocoder', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-geocoder'

pod 'Alamofire'



pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'

end
```

when I run command pod install it shows me error like this

https://pastebin.com/x3iBc7PD

Any idea How can i solve this?

Comment: what version of pod did you use to install? have you tried downgrading it to match the release of RN v0.59?

Comment: I tried with downgrade but not working, My current pod version in 1.12.1 @kenmistry

Comment: the last release of RN v0.59 that i can find is on Jul 2, 2019 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases?q=0.59&expanded=true). so the matching pod version back in Jul 2019 is 1.7.5 (https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods/versions). i think you should try using this specific pod version to do the installation.